# JavaScript array map change order of elements when i use Number()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am makeing a `GET` request to the server and in response i am getting an array of objects.

```js
axios.get(`${HOST}/operations/post-flight-graph-data?orgId=${orgId}&ecoId=${ecoId}`)
      .then(res => {
        // order numbers
        const orderNumbers = res.data.map(data => data.order_No);
        // battery percentage before flight
        const chargingBeforePercentage = res.data.map(data => {
          return {
            x: data.order_No,
            y: parseFloat((data.charging?.before_Per) || 0)
          }
        });
        // battery percentage after flight
        const chargingAfterPercentage = res.data.map(data => {
          return {
            x: data.order_No,
            y: parseFloat((data.charging?.after_Per) || 0)
          }
        });
        console.log('res.data', res.data)
        console.log({ orderNumbers })
        console.log({ chargingBeforePercentage })
        console.log({ chargingAfterPercentage})
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

### Returned data from server

```js
[
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "51",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "1"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "51",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "7"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "99",
            "after_Per": "86"
        },
        "order_No": "1"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "51",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "9"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "10"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "100",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "11"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "100",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "12"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "51",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "14"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "83",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "15"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "after_Per": "51",
            "before_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "13"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "100",
            "after_Per": "69"
        },
        "order_No": "8"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "100",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "18"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "20"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "before_Per": "100",
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "17"
    },
    {
        "charging": {
            "after_Per": "51"
        },
        "order_No": "19"
    }
]
```

### orderNumbers on console

```js
[
    "1",
    "7",
    "1",
    "9",
    "10",
    "11",
    "12",
    "14",
    "15",
    "13",
    "8",
    "18",
    "20",
    "17",
    "19"
]
```

### chargingBeforePercentage on console

```js
[
    {
        "x": "1",
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": "7",
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": "1",
        "y": 99
    },
    {
        "x": "9",
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": "10",
        "y": 0
    },
    {
        "x": "11",
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": "12",
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": "14",
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": "15",
        "y": 83
    },
    {
        "x": "13",
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": "8",
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": "18",
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": "20",
        "y": 0
    },
    {
        "x": "17",
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": "19",
        "y": 0
    }
]
```

You can see that elements if `orderNumbers` and `x` property of `chargingBeforePercentage` is a string. But, for my operation i need to convert them into integer. So, i used `Number()` to cast string into integer.

To do that i converted `data.order_No` into `Number(data.order_No)`, then order of output changed.

```js
    GET(`operations/post-flight-graph-data?orgId=${orgId}&ecoId=${ecoId}`)
      .then(res => {
        // order numbers
        const orderNumbers = res.data.map(data => Number(data.order_No));
        // battery percentage before flight
        const chargingBeforePercentage = res.data.map(data => {
          return {
            x: Number(data.order_No),
            y: parseFloat((data.charging?.before_Per) || 0)
          }
        });
        // battery percentage after flight
        const chargingAfterPercentage = res.data.map(data => {
          return {
            x: Number(data.order_No),
            y: parseFloat((data.charging?.after_Per) || 0)
          }
        });
        console.log('res.data', res.data)
        console.log({ orderNumbers })
        console.log({ chargingBeforePercentage })
        console.log({ chargingAfterPercentage})
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

### orderNumbers after `Number(data.order_No)`

```js
[
    1,
    7,
    1,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    14,
    15,
    13,
    8,
    18,
    20,
    17,
    19
]
```

### chargingBeforePercentage after `Number(data.order_No)`

```js
[
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 99
    },
    {
        "x": 7,
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": 9,
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": 10,
        "y": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 11,
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": 12,
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": 14,
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": 15,
        "y": 83
    },
    {
        "x": 13,
        "y": 51
    },
    {
        "x": 8,
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": 18,
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": 20,
        "y": 0
    },
    {
        "x": 17,
        "y": 100
    },
    {
        "x": 19,
        "y": 0
    }
]
```

You can notice the  change in `chargingBeforePercentage`.

**before using `Number()`**

```js
chargingBeforePercentage[0].x = '1'
chargingBeforePercentage[1].x = '7'
chargingBeforePercentage[2].x = '1'
```

**after using `Number()`**

```js
chargingBeforePercentage[0].x = 1
chargingBeforePercentage[1].x = 1
chargingBeforePercentage[2].x = 7
```

### Why this is happening?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add a [mcve]. An [mcve] requires a minimal set of input, actual output and expected output that shows the behavior. We also need the code that does produce the "actual output" (I don't see any `Number(...)` calls in your script.)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's happening but I'm pretty sure you're mistaken. What you describe is simply not possible; mapping will not change the order like that. My guess is the order changed on the server, and you were looking at the outputs of two separate requests. So unless you post a screenshot of console output that shows the order has changed, I'm filing this under "not reproducible"

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: @Andreas `Add a minimal reproducible example` the above code is complete in itself, you can see there is no other function or anything involved

Comment: @ChrisG `What you describe is simply not possible` i know `.map()` can not change the order, but this is what exactly happening.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information as text, not as a picture of text. Why: ` i have posted the code as it is, image consist of only output.

Comment: The part, where you use Number() to convert x is missing. -- If you don't provide a full log of before/after, with the code you used, no one will be able to explain it. -- By now, you can call it `magic` or `not reproductible`.

Comment: @ChrisG `My guess is the order changed on the server`  you can have a look at the image  below **Returned data from server**. This is what is returned from the server

Comment: try to post this question by adding your res.data so we can work with it. map would not change the order and since we can't reproduce your code, no one can help you. add something like const myData = res.data (paste here what you get from server). adding it in a screenshot won't help anyone reproducing your code.

Comment: @J_K okey, i am going to post the data as well

Comment: @Rahul you claim that Number() changed the mapping order, and it's nowhere to be seen in the code example you shared. Unless you share that no one has a clue what is happening and why.

Comment: @Rahul - You're expecting people to read the console output. Thus, it should be provided as readable text. (The image is *also* nice, but not a replacement for something that can be easily read, including by visually-impaired people who may be able to help you.)

Comment: @Rahul also show us where you used Number()

Comment: @J_K i have mntioned `To do that i converted data.order_No into Number(data.order_No), then order of output changed.`

Comment: Look, there's two options: either (1) map and/or Number are fundamentally broken, or (2) you're mistaken. I'll go with (2) unless you post code that reproduces the problem or show a consistent before/after log

Comment: @Rahul I understand, but your question is not visible where you did it

Comment: @J_K okey, i am going to update this in question as well

Comment: Here's live code: https://jsfiddle.net/rdh3nkx0/ as expected, the order does not change at all

Comment: @ChrisG yeah, but you can see the update question, i am not able to solve it. There is no other functions or anything involved. But, still i am getting wrong output.

Comment: @ChrisG although i am using `react`, is this effect?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as a runable code snippet. A network request or React shouldn't be necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Using React shouldn't matter, but keep in mind that logging state right after changing it will show old values (because setting state is async).

Comment: I'll let you know guys, that what was the issue. Also, thanks for your time

Comment: Are you saying setting React state being async was indeed causing the issue?

Comment: @ChrisG `console.log('res.data', res.data)
        console.log({ orderNumbers })
        console.log({ chargingBeforePercentage })
        console.log({ chargingAfterPercentage})` all variables are normal JS variables, not react state.

Comment: Yeah, your previous comment sounded like you had found what was causing it. Anyway: can you still reproduce this? Does the change in order still happen with your current code? Can you create a single screenshot of console output that shows this happening? Because I haven't seen that yet.

Comment: @ChrisG there is not improvement.

Answer (score -3):

As you can see in this snippet, map doesn't change the order.

```js
let myData = [{
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "51",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "1"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "51",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "7"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "99",
      "after_Per": "86"
    },
    "order_No": "1"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "51",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "9"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "10"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "100",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "11"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "100",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "12"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "51",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "14"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "83",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "15"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "after_Per": "51",
      "before_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "13"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "100",
      "after_Per": "69"
    },
    "order_No": "8"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "100",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "18"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "20"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "before_Per": "100",
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "17"
  },
  {
    "charging": {
      "after_Per": "51"
    },
    "order_No": "19"
  }
]
const orderNumbers = myData.map(data => data.order_No);
// battery percentage before flight
const chargingBeforePercentage = myData.map(data => {
  return {
    x: parseInt(data.order_No),
    y: parseFloat((data.charging?.before_Per) || 0)
  }
});
// battery percentage after flight
const chargingAfterPercentage = myData.map(data => {
  return {
    x: parseInt(data.order_No),
    y: parseFloat((data.charging?.after_Per) || 0)
  }
});
//console.log('res.data', myData)
console.log(
  orderNumbers
)
console.log({
  chargingBeforePercentage
})
console.log({
  chargingAfterPercentage
})
```

Comment: Using Number() is fine.

Comment: same behaviour `parseInt`

Comment: regardless, the order should be the same. check your server response.

Comment: `regardless, the order should be the same. check your server response` i already  mentioned server response that i am getting on client

Comment: @Rahul run the code snippet I added. The order stays the same.

Comment: The actual question here isn't whether map changes the order (it doesn't), it's why OP is convinced the order changed after calling map. Your answer isn't answering that.

Comment: @ChrisG that's why suggesting to check his get request because he thinks Number() is the issue, which is not the case.

Comment: @J_K Technically speaking, `.map` should not change the order of the input array and `Number()` should not effect anything here.  But, as i already mentioned that the issue is coming when i change `data.order_No` into `Number(data.order_No)`. This behaviour is unexpected, if there is any issue in the data returned from the server, then it should the issue should occur in both the cases.

Comment: @J_K I have also posted the data returned form the server, so there is no issue with the server react data.

Comment: @ChrisG as we have tested the code on `jsfiddle`, so i can certainly say that the issue is not with the code it self. I am using `React`, so there could be some issue from that side

Comment: I'll let you know guys, that what was the issue. Also, thanks for your time